How to create a rank from ranks?
I have calculated ranks for each row based on a condition on each column. Now I have,
         col1  col2 col3
item 1    2     1     2
item 2    3     2     1
item 3    1     3     3

and so on. 

The weights are equal for each column. I tried averaging and sum, but it gives the same final rank with ties. Is there a way to get unique ranks? I saw a similar question, but could not find any agreed upon solution.

Your example yields 3 unique ranks when summing, or averaging the ranks row-wise. Can you clarify what you mean, or provide an example where the issue occurs?

There are 15 rows and 8 columns overall, so when summing, some rows end up having same aggregates resulting in ties.

If you don't want to accept ties, it's up to you to weigh the columns. Which of the following do you want to be ranked higher? Any metric that is indifferent to the columns will tie item 1 and item 2.
       | col1 | col2 |
item 1 | 2    | 1    |
item 2 | 1    | 2    |


It should be obvious that, if you rank each column independently, the sum of ranks for all columns will be equal (and equal to $n(n+1)/2$, where $n$ is the number of rows). To get a "single" rank, accross all 3 columns, you need a single metric which can be compared accross all 3 columns. Which you probably do not have? But maybe each column measures the same phenomenon, just under different conditions; then you can compare accross columns, and create a single rank for all 3 columns. JUst stack the 3 columns into a new one, create an additional indicator column which contains the ID of the column each datapoint came from, and sort these 2 new columns; then you can rank these 2 new columns, assign ranks, and then sum these "global" ranks for each column ID. The grand total will be $(3n+1)3n/2$, but each column ID will have a different sum of "global" ranks.
More importantly, why are you trying to get a unique rank accross multiple columns? And what are these specific columns? What are they measuring? If you could share a bit of the background/context, maybe we could provide a better answer.

Thanks for your input, I need the ranks for each row, not column. There are 15 rows i.e. items and 8 columns.

Your example data had equal sums per column, and different sums per row. So not a great indication of your problem? Fundamentally, you can not prevent ties per row (what if 2 rows had exactly the same ranks for each column?). And using weights for the columns does not change this (easy to create counter-examples). Can you explain why ties are "bad" in your case; what problem do they create? Maybe there is a way to handle ties which would still give you the answer you seek?

Thank you for your input. I found some research papers which discussed the techniques to rank based on multiple criteria.  They do discuss creating weights for each column.
